# Raise event which relays another one

Tags: c#, .net, events

I'd like to relay a event. Currently i intercept InnerEvent in the constructor and relay like this:

```
obj.InnerEvent+=(...)=>{
    if(OuterEvent != null)
        OuterEvent(...);
}
```

But it looks bad so i find out relay can be done at event level with add/remove keyword like this:

```
event Handler OuterEvent{
  add{ obj.InnerEvent+=value;}
  remove{ obj.InnerEvent+=value;}
}
```

But at this point i cannot raise my OuterEvent no more. I know why it is not directly possible ([read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015166/c-event-with-explicity-add-remove-typical-event)) but i cannot figure out a decent way to keep raising my OuterEvent. Should i bind and relay in the  constructor as i always did? What's the best technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense, `OuterEvent` does not exist as an event any more when you use the second approach. It is now nothing but a way of subscribing to `obj`'s `InnerEvent`, and therefore `OuterEvent` is now effectively the same event as `InnerEvent`: there is no delegate backing `OuterEvent` that invokes just the subscribers to that event. The only way to invoke `OuterEvent` is thus to raise `InnerEvent`.

The workaround would be to expose a means of raising `InnerEvent` from outside `obj`, but I'd consider this bad practice. I'd prefer sticking to the first method if you need to invoke `OuterEvent` from your outer class as well. In cases where `OuterEvent` is truly only forwarding `InnerEvent`, the second approach is quite elegant.